# AJAX call keeps returning Javascript console error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to set up a very basic ajax call, but I keep getting a console log error. I cannot find the error

> TypeError: undefined is not a function (near '...$.ajax...')

```js
function loadimage() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "../../includes/ajax.php",
    success: function(data) {
      $('.maincontainer-inner').css('background-image', 'url(' + data + ')');
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" onclick="return false" onmousedown="javascript:loadimage();"><span id="reload">Reload</span></a>
```

Comment: Is jquery included and loaded?

Comment: yes it is .....

Comment: is `loadimage` in the global context? (though, the error should be that `loadimage` is not defined in that case - I too doubt this code is the real problem

Comment: Check for early errors before click the anchor tag if there is any

Comment: got it work, it seems that "loadimage" is not appropriate as a function name, I renamed it to "getnewimage", and it works now ... douh

Comment: There's nothing inherently invalid about `loadimage`, you're probably just redefining it somewhere else

Answer (score -2):

If you use `$.ajax` than you must define call type and data type also like 
Call Type is **Get,Post, Delete or PUT** and also add data type **Json** or any thing. 
Also add error method if response contain any error.